# Not able to perform click action with email chat support option

Tags: java, email, selenium-webdriver, xpath, ui-automation

```
<a href="mailto:support@gmail.co" title="Contact Support" >
```

There is an icon which hold the above elements , when clicked on that icon, it will open the email conversation like this

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?fs=1&tf=cm&source=mailto&to=support@gmail.co

When I do click action on that icon there is no response but click action performed , is there any restriction behind this when do automation , other icon after this icons are all working fine

I tried below and nothing worked

1. normal `click()`
2. `click()` using keyboard
3. `click()` using Action class

```
public LoginPage clickContactSupportLnk()
    {
        
       WebElement inputField = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"pcs\"]"));
       Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
       actions.moveToElement(inputField).click().build().perform();
       waitForGivenTime(5);
       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.urlToBe("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?           fs=1&tf=cm&source=mailto&to=support@gmail.co"));
        return this;

    }


public LoginPage clickContactSupportLnk()
    {
    
      WebElement inputField = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Sign Up')]"));
      inputField.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
      inputField.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
      waitForGivenTime(5);
      wait.until(ExpectedConditions.urlToBe("https:URL"));
      return this;

    }
```